# The connection was reset with Laravel 7 also 8

Tags: php, laravel, connection-reset

I have a problem with a Laravel application. When serving the app, does not matter if its with >>php artisan serve<< or Apache, the application works at first, but then breaks with "The connection was reset". I looked at the apache logs, path is /var/log/apache2/error.log, there i see:

```
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

php artisan serve log.:

```
[Fri Jun 11 00:34:36 2021] 127.0.0.1:38974 Accepted
[Fri Jun 11 00:34:36 2021] 127.0.0.1:38974 Closing
Environment modified. Restarting server...
[Fri Jun 11 00:34:36 2021] PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

I did edit php.ini, disabled opcache as so `opcache.enable=0`.
Also added below code at the start of .htaccess

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off
php_flag xcache.size 0
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```

Any advice on where to get additional logs or what are possible causes. Thanks

Comment: try adding `php_flag opcache.enable Off` in your `.htaccess` in the `public` directory

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.

try adding `php_flag opcache.enable Off` in your `.htaccess` in the public directory (like Alberto said in the comments)